# Memory leak with timer.performWithDelay

Tags: memory-leaks, coronasdk

I'm not sure why the following example code doesn't free up all the timer memory. It starts at around 133kb, if you tap the screen it creates 10,000 timers. After they have run, they should be cleaned up. However after removing all the timers, it levels out at about 389kb.

Am I missing something?

```
local timersFired = 0
local timers = {}
local maxTimers = 10000

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", function(e)
    if(e.phase == "began") then
        print("TIMERS CREATED")
        timers = {}
        for i=1,maxTimers do
            table.insert(timers, timer.performWithDelay(3000, function(e)
                timersFired = timersFired + 1
            end, 1))
        end
    end
end)

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", function(e)
    if(timersFired == maxTimers) then
        print("KILLED TIMERS")
        for i=1,maxTimers do
            local aTimer = timers[i]
            timer.cancel(aTimer)
            timers[i] = nil
        end

        timers = nil
        timersFired = 0
    end

    collectgarbage("collect")
    print( "MemUsage: " .. collectgarbage("count") )
end)
```

Comment: I read this many times, and I can only conclude that Corona SDK is the one leaking :/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not your only problem, but the for loop that removes the timers will only remove half of them.

The loop runs from `1 to #timers`.  The first time through, `i` is 1, and it removes the first timer.  The second time through, `i` is incremented to 2, but the elements in the array have shifted down in the meantime, so the code skips timer #2, and proceeds to delete what was originally timer #3.  And so on.

The end result is that you only remove the timers from the odd positions in the timers array, leaving half of them still taking memory.

A `while (#timers > 0) do` loop will work better, or a `for i = #timers, 1, -1 do` loop that removes the last timer each time.

You can verify if this is a part of the problem by creating perhaps only 10 timers.  Print "created" as each one that's created, and print "deleted" as each is destroyed.  You should see 10 creates and 10 deletes.  (I'm thinking you'll only see 5 deletes.)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the problem. timers[i] = nil does not shift down the other elements, table.remove would do that. I verified that 10 created and 10 deleted statements are printed to double check.